Why is this sliding query not producing the correct results?
What I am trying to do is
I have a nearly identical situation to this post, and this one (I'd rather not use 4 separate lag fields), and I even found this example that says that basically I need a range of rows. None of them produce the right results.
The objective is to create a series of before and after error rates, grouped by DEFINTION and FOR_DATE where before is all data 4 days before the given date, and after is all data after; trying to find spikes in the error rate.
so,
before is:
sum(system_errors(n-1..n-4))/sum(total_run(n-1..n-4)) group by FOR_DATE, DEFINITION
and
after:
sum(system_errors(n..))/sum(total_run(n..)) group by FOR_DATE, DEFINITION
To put it in psuedo math terms
Here are some fiddle examples of what I have tried
My ideal results would look like this, where 7/10/24 is the mid date:



DATE
DEFINITION
SYSTEM_ERRORS
TOTAL_RUN
BEFORE
AFTER




7/6/24
BAT
1920
6258
null
0.013136


7/6/24
BAZ
35
256353
null
0.000066


7/6/24
FOO
134
18487
null
0.013136


7/7/24
BAT
1972
4529
null
0.013883


7/7/24
BAZ
10
236304
null
0.000058


7/7/24
FOO
132
18492
null
0.013883


7/8/24
BAT
1927
7972
null
0.014864


7/8/24
BAZ
46
308912
null
0.00006


7/8/24
FOO
120
18008
null
0.014864


7/9/24
BAT
1853
8494
null
0.016217


7/9/24
BAZ
6
320445
null
0.000045


7/9/24
FOO
104
17870
null
0.016217


7/10/24
BAT
1824
7571
0.006726
0.018253


7/10/24
BAZ
35
319427
0.000086
0.00005


7/10/24
FOO
1236
18980
0.006726
0.018253


7/11/24
BAT
1858
8143
0.021704
0.005948


7/11/24
BAZ
5
322179
0.000082
0.000034


7/11/24
FOO
110
17972
0.021704
0.005948


7/12/24
BAT
1833
8011
0.021557
0.005891


7/12/24
BAZ
3
318872
0.000072
0.000041


7/12/24
FOO
108
18082
0.021557
0.005891


7/13/24
BAT
1533
4982
0.021371
0.00585


7/13/24
BAZ
29
255573
0.000038
0.000061


7/13/24
FOO
104
18151
0.021371
0.00585


7/14/24
BAT
1564
2920
0.021289
0.005971


7/14/24
BAZ
1
233627
0.000059
0.000004


7/14/24
FOO
108
18087
0.021289
0.005971



I've updated the expected data table, as I realize I didn't compute it correctly

You appear to want to use analytic functions with a RANGE window. You have not explained the calculation that you are expecting to use to generate your ideal results but assuming that you want the average of the SYSTEM_ERRORS/TOTAL_RUNS for the both the range 4 days preceding until before the current day and the range from the current day including all future days then you can use:
select FOR_DATE,
       DEFINITION AS def,
       SYSTEM_ERRORS,
       TOTAL_RUNS,
       ROUND(
         AVG(SYSTEM_ERRORS/TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING
                     AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
         ),
         4
       ) as avg_prev_erate,
       ROUND(
         AVG(SYSTEM_ERRORS/TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                     AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         ),
         4
       ) as avg_fut_erate
from   table_name
ORDER BY for_date, definition;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (for_date, definition, system_errors, total_runs) AS
  select DATE '2024-07-06', 'FOO', 134, 18487 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-06', 'BAZ', 35, 256353 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-06', 'BAT', 1920, 6258 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-07', 'FOO', 132, 18492 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-07', 'BAZ', 10, 236304 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-07', 'BAT', 1972, 4529 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-08', 'FOO', 120, 18008 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-08', 'BAZ', 46, 308912 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-08', 'BAT', 1927, 7972 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-09', 'FOO', 104, 17870 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-09', 'BAZ', 6, 320445 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-09', 'BAT', 1853, 8494 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-10', 'FOO', 1236, 18980 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-10', 'BAZ', 35, 319427 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-10', 'BAT', 1824, 7571 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-11', 'FOO', 110, 17972 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-11', 'BAZ', 5, 322179 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-11', 'BAT', 1858, 8143 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-12', 'FOO', 108, 18082 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-12', 'BAZ', 3, 318872 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-12', 'BAT', 1833, 8011 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-13', 'FOO', 104, 18151 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-13', 'BAZ', 29, 255573 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-13', 'BAT', 1533, 4982 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-14', 'FOO', 108, 18087 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-14', 'BAZ', 1, 233627 from dual union all
  select DATE '2024-07-14', 'BAT', 1564, 2920 from dual

Outputs:



FOR_DATE
DEF
SYSTEM_ERRORS
TOTAL_RUNS
AVG_PREV_ERATE
AVG_FUT_ERATE




2024-07-06 00:00:00
BAT
1920
6258
null
.3048


2024-07-06 00:00:00
BAZ
35
256353
null
.0001


2024-07-06 00:00:00
FOO
134
18487
null
.0129


2024-07-07 00:00:00
BAT
1972
4529
.3068
.3046


2024-07-07 00:00:00
BAZ
10
236304
.0001
.0001


2024-07-07 00:00:00
FOO
132
18492
.0072
.0136


2024-07-08 00:00:00
BAT
1927
7972
.3711
.2859


2024-07-08 00:00:00
BAZ
46
308912
.0001
.0001


2024-07-08 00:00:00
FOO
120
18008
.0072
.0145


2024-07-09 00:00:00
BAT
1853
8494
.328
.2932


2024-07-09 00:00:00
BAZ
6
320445
.0001
0


2024-07-09 00:00:00
FOO
104
17870
.007
.0158


2024-07-10 00:00:00
BAT
1824
7571
.3005
.3082


2024-07-10 00:00:00
BAZ
35
319427
.0001
.0001


2024-07-10 00:00:00
FOO
1236
18980
.0067
.0178


2024-07-11 00:00:00
BAT
1858
8143
.2841
.3251


2024-07-11 00:00:00
BAZ
5
322179
.0001
0


2024-07-11 00:00:00
FOO
110
17972
.0212
.0059


2024-07-12 00:00:00
BAT
1833
8011
.2322
.3574


2024-07-12 00:00:00
BAZ
3
318872
.0001
0


2024-07-12 00:00:00
FOO
108
18082
.0209
.0059


2024-07-13 00:00:00
BAT
1533
4982
.229
.4217


2024-07-13 00:00:00
BAZ
29
255573
0
.0001


2024-07-13 00:00:00
FOO
104
18151
.0208
.0059


2024-07-14 00:00:00
BAT
1564
2920
.2514
.5356


2024-07-14 00:00:00
BAZ
1
233627
.0001
0


2024-07-14 00:00:00
FOO
108
18087
.0207
.006




If you want to have all 4 days of previous error rates in the average (and NULL if there are not 4 days of previous results) then:
select FOR_DATE,
       DEFINITION AS def,
       SYSTEM_ERRORS,
       TOTAL_RUNS,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(FOR_DATE) OVER (
              partition by DEFINITION
              order by FOR_DATE
              RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING
                        AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
            ) = 4
       THEN ROUND(
              AVG(SYSTEM_ERRORS/TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
                partition by DEFINITION
                order by FOR_DATE
                RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING
                          AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
              ),
              4
            )
       END as avg_prev_erate,
       ROUND(
         AVG(SYSTEM_ERRORS/TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                     AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         ),
         4
       ) as avg_fut_erate
from   table_name
ORDER BY for_date, definition;

Which outputs:



FOR_DATE
DEF
SYSTEM_ERRORS
TOTAL_RUNS
AVG_PREV_ERATE
AVG_FUT_ERATE




2024-07-06 00:00:00
BAT
1920
6258
null
.3048


2024-07-06 00:00:00
BAZ
35
256353
null
.0001


2024-07-06 00:00:00
FOO
134
18487
null
.0129


2024-07-07 00:00:00
BAT
1972
4529
null
.3046


2024-07-07 00:00:00
BAZ
10
236304
null
.0001


2024-07-07 00:00:00
FOO
132
18492
null
.0136


2024-07-08 00:00:00
BAT
1927
7972
null
.2859


2024-07-08 00:00:00
BAZ
46
308912
null
.0001


2024-07-08 00:00:00
FOO
120
18008
null
.0145


2024-07-09 00:00:00
BAT
1853
8494
null
.2932


2024-07-09 00:00:00
BAZ
6
320445
null
0


2024-07-09 00:00:00
FOO
104
17870
null
.0158


2024-07-10 00:00:00
BAT
1824
7571
.3005
.3082


2024-07-10 00:00:00
BAZ
35
319427
.0001
.0001


2024-07-10 00:00:00
FOO
1236
18980
.0067
.0178


2024-07-11 00:00:00
BAT
1858
8143
.2841
.3251


2024-07-11 00:00:00
BAZ
5
322179
.0001
0


2024-07-11 00:00:00
FOO
110
17972
.0212
.0059


2024-07-12 00:00:00
BAT
1833
8011
.2322
.3574


2024-07-12 00:00:00
BAZ
3
318872
.0001
0


2024-07-12 00:00:00
FOO
108
18082
.0209
.0059


2024-07-13 00:00:00
BAT
1533
4982
.229
.4217


2024-07-13 00:00:00
BAZ
29
255573
0
.0001


2024-07-13 00:00:00
FOO
104
18151
.0208
.0059


2024-07-14 00:00:00
BAT
1564
2920
.2514
.5356


2024-07-14 00:00:00
BAZ
1
233627
.0001
0


2024-07-14 00:00:00
FOO
108
18087
.0207
.006




An alternative calculation could be:
select FOR_DATE,
       DEFINITION AS def,
       SYSTEM_ERRORS,
       TOTAL_RUNS,
       ROUND(
         SUM(SYSTEM_ERRORS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING
                     AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
         ) 
         /
         SUM(TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '4' DAY PRECEDING
                     AND INTERVAL '1' SECOND PRECEDING
         ),
         4
       ) as avg_prev_erate,
       ROUND(
         SUM(SYSTEM_ERRORS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                     AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         )
         /
         SUM(TOTAL_RUNS) OVER (
           partition by DEFINITION
           order by FOR_DATE
           RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                     AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
         ),
         4
       ) as avg_fut_erate
from   table_name
ORDER BY for_date, definition;

If you want 4 days worth of results for this calculation then wrap it in a CASE expression and check that there is a COUNT of 4 days results similar to the second query.
fiddle

I appreciate your input. I realize my expected results table is wrong and I am updating it. Once I do that, I'd still appreciate your updated input, if needed.

I've updated the expected table. You're understanding is completely correct.

@MTO when I run your query the AVG_PREV_RATE always shows as 1. The future error rate looks mostly aligned with my manual query, so I am going to assume there was a copy/paste error when I put together the results.

@MTO Ok, I fixed the 1 problem; not sure how it ever happened. These results are starting to look correct. And, I am very likely missing something. In your results table, you produce previous results on 7/7/24 which shouldn't be possible since there isn't 4 days worth of data at that point. However, at 7/10 it all lines up

@ChristianBongiorno Updated - it helps if you clearly define the logic you are trying to implement and all your requirements in the question when you first ask it because the initial version of your question did not have 3 days of NULL values at the start, there was only 1 day.

@ChristianBongiorno A window on an analytic function does not look for results filling every possible value of the window (how would it when a DATE contains a time component and would need a value not just for every day but every second of every day) it just looks to see if there is at least one value in the range and then calculates using whatever values it finds in that range whether there is 1 or 4 or 1,000,000.

AH! Hmmm, I guess that'll be ok since I will actually be running this against a whole lot of data - the chances that someone will look at this edge case is slim to none. Could I use lag for this job?

@MTO I realize the original data was wrong, Sorry.

@ChristianBongiorno Have you tried the second query that I added to the answer? Assuming that you only have one row per day per definition then it should do what you want.

Yeah, that nails it. Thanks!

I have tried to give your desired output, firstly i created 3 table from your three query and tried CTE to give your output.
    WITH combined AS (
  SELECT
t1.FOR_DATE,
t1.DEFINITION AS define,
t1.SYSTEM_ERRORS,
t1.TOTAL_RUNs,
t2.previous_total_run,
t3.rate
  FROM zzz_table1 t1
  JOIN zzz_table2 t2 ON t1.FOR_DATE = t2.FOR_DATE AND t1.DEFINITION = t2.DEFINITION
  JOIN zzz_table3 t3 ON t1.FOR_DATE = t3.FOR_DATE AND t1.DEFINITION = t3.DEFINITION
),
calculated AS (
  SELECT
FOR_DATE,
define,
SYSTEM_ERRORS,
TOTAL_RUNs,
LAG(SYSTEM_ERRORS / TOTAL_RUNs) OVER (PARTITION BY define ORDER BY FOR_DATE) AS lagged_before,
SYSTEM_ERRORS / TOTAL_RUNs AS after_value
  FROM combined
)
SELECT
  FOR_DATE,
  define,
  SYSTEM_ERRORS,
  TOTAL_RUNs,
  Round(CASE
WHEN lagged_before = 0 THEN NULL
ELSE lagged_before
  END ,4)AS BEFORE,
  Round(after_value,4) AS AFTER
FROM calculated
ORDER BY FOR_DATE,define

Kindly check the fiddle output https://dbfiddle.uk/cVW-6e2M if this will work for you or not.

Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
